# How do I Fix Undefined property: stdClass::$flash_error In Controller

Tags: laravel, controller

Here is the details of the project

```
/**
     * Create Ride.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create_ride(Request $request)
    {   
        //dd('hii');
        $data = $this->UserAPI->send_request($request);
        
        if(isset($data->getData()->error) && $data->getData()->error=='dashboard')
        {
            return redirect('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', $data->getData()->flash_error? $data->getData()->flash_error:$data->getData()->error);
    }
```

I have Tried

```
 return redirect()->back()->with('message', $data->getData()->$flash_error? $data->getData()->flash_error:$data->getData()->error);
```

but It Didnt Work.

please I need A help.

Comment: i think you were looking for `??` and not `?:` ... `A ?? B` IS `isset(A) ? A : B` .... on a side note, what you currently have also can be shortened `A ? A : B` IS `A ?: B`

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you access a property on an object or array.

```
$data->getData()->$flash_error
```

Firstly i would try to `dd()` the data to see what type it is. Run the code with the following.

```
dd($data->getData());
```

If the data is an `object`, it should be.

```
$data->getData()->flash_error
```

If it's an array, it should be.

```
$data->getData()['flash_error']
```